# Why am I getting the error "undefined reference to main" even though main is properly defined?

Tags: c, gcc

I am running Xubuntu on a vm (because it was easier to do that compared to getting gcc on windows).
I have tried all of the different arguments for compiling the program (eg. running `gcc filename.c` and `gcc filename.c -o filename`), but none of them have changed the outcome.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    printf("a");

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried using `main()` and `main(arg...[or whatever it is I can't remember])` and I get the same error.

Comment: What is `std.io`? Did you mean `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: My only guess is that maybe you're not saving the file, or accidentally saving it to the wrong place.  (Easy mistake to make.) Try running `cat filename.c` in the same terminal you're running gcc in to see the contents of the file.

Comment: I remember saving it, and saving it to the right place.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted.  There's not a C compiler in the universe that won't compile that properly.  You've absolutely got your `main()` function properly defined.  So there must be something else going on, that we can't see.

Comment: I'll try reinstalling Xubuntu and see if that helps.

Comment: Before reinstalling, try copying and pasting (not retyping) the exact code you've posted here back to `filename.c`, and trying again.  Maybe also copy and paste the exact command line `gcc filename.c -o filename`, too.

Comment: I can't copy and paste the code because it's in a vm, but the code in the post should be identical to the code in the vm (I also have already uninstalled it and am reinstalling it now :/).

The name of the file is "test.c", if that helps

Comment: "I can't copy and paste the code because it's in a vm" That's not how it's supposed to be, BTW. You'll hate the VM experience until you get at least copy-paste working between the host and the VM. It's supposed to work when things are set up correctly. As for using gcc on Windows: there's no need for that. Visual Studio Community should do the job, or just use Visual Studio Build Tools if you need only the compiler and not the IDE. You can get mingw on Windows for "free" by installing Qt (you also get a nice IDE - Qt Creator).

Comment: If you're using Windows 10, you can install Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store, apt install build-essential, and the gcc compiler right there inside Windows.

Comment: the code is good. the command is good. it might be environment problem, or there might be some multi-char blank in the source code.